# Semigroup cohomology of the semigroup of Hilbert polynomials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, group-cohomology

In my research, I have to deal with the following cohomology:

Let $G$ be the semigroup of Hilbert polynomials, which as a subset of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, consists of the Hilbert polynomials of all subschemes of $\mathbb{P}^N$ for various $N$, and the semigroup structure is given by product of polynomials. A theorem of Macaulay characterizes this semi-group completely.
Consider $\mathbb{Z}/(2)$ as a trivial $G$-module. 
I have to calculate
$H^2(G,\mathbb{Z}/(2))$.

I try to apply the universal coefficient theorem to do a reduction, but due to a lack of knowledge about $G$, I can't get further information.

Is it possible to calculate this group explicitly?

Comment: What does Macaulay's theorem say?

Comment: Do you count the zero polynomial?

Comment: If you don't include zero as a Hilbert polynomial you have a cancellative commutative semigroup and so its cohomology on a module with trivial actin is the same as the cohomology of its Grothendieck group (or group completion of group of fractions).

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg On the other hand, if zero is there then the answer will be zero - for example, since cohomology in question coincidies with the cohomology of the classifying space, which is contractible for semigroups with a zero.

Comment: Yes. I assume that one would not want the zero for this reason.  I suspect the group completion is free abelian but don't know enough about the semigroup in question.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg You can find Macaulay's theorem here http://comp.uark.edu/~ashleykw/SCATCooper.pdf   Page 6. I do not assume 0 is there, so the problem is more tricky

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I do not include 0, so I can only reduce the problem a little bit by the universal coefficient theorem.

Comment: Without a zero the cohomology is the same as the cohomology group of the Grothendieck group of this commutative cancellative monoid by Quillen's Thm A because the classifying space of the monoid and group are the same.

Comment: Your monoid consists of certain elements with consists ten 1 if I understood correctly. The constant term 1 polynomials form a free commutative monoid on the irreducible ones. And so this bigger monoid has a free abelian group of infinite rank as Grothendieck group. So your monoid also has a free abelian Grothendieck group.

Comment: If you can figure out the rank of that free abelian group then your cohomology is easy to get.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Constant term of the Hilbert polynomial, although always an integer, is not 1 in general. For example, the Hilbert polynomial of a degree $d$ plane curve has constant term $-\frac{d(d-3)}2$.

Comment: It might be that minimal generators of the semigroup are Hilbert polynomials of irreducible varieties. Note however that the semigroup of varieties themselves (w. r. t. Cartesian product) is not cancellative: in an answer to [a question here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/254240/41291) is mentioned [an example by Shioda](https://repository.dl.itc.u-tokyo.ac.jp/?action=repository_uri&item_id=39716&file_id=19&file_no=1) of pairwise nonisomorphic elliptic curves $E$, $E'$, $E''$ with $E\times E'\cong E\times E''$.

Comment: I had thought from the article the OP linked that the value at 0 is 1.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg In the linked text, everything is in terms of Hilbert *functions*. The value at 0 of the Hilbert function is 1 by definition, but its values only coincide with values of the Hilbert polynomial after certain $n_0$ (called [Hilbert regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_series_and_Hilbert_polynomial#Definitions_and_main_properties)).

Comment: Ok. I haven't thought about hilbrrt polynomials in 20 years.